# How to determine request input array is empty?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2. I have a question. If I send a request like

```
http://localhost/test?sports[]=soccer&sports[]=basketball
```

I can get sports as an array with 2 elements.

But if I send request like:

```
http://localhost/test?sports[]
```

I get it by `$sports = $request->input('sports')`, I think it is an empty array, but it's actually not. I `var_dump()` it:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

So someone can tell me how can I determine the request input array data is empty?

---

Supplement:

My `routes.php` here:

```
Route::get('/test',function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    var_dump($request->has('sports'));
});
```

I access `http://localhost/test?sports[]`

It output true.

Comment: var_dump `$request->has('sports')` check the output should be false.

Comment: No, it output true.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any built-in functionality for what you need but you can create a `Request` macro as:

```
Request::macro('someCoolName', function ($key) {
    return is_array($this->input($key)) && (count($this->input($key)) == 1) && empty($this->input($key)[0]) ? [] : $this->input($key);
});
```

*Note - Add it in `boot()` method of `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`.*

And then you can use it as:

```
$request->someCoolName('sports'); // returns []
```

It returns emprty array `[]` if your URL is like `http://localhost/test?sports[]`